# Strapi GraphQL policies

Tags: graphql, strapi

I try to use GraphQL module on Strapi project. I would like add new Query. You can see my code :

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/recipes",
      "handler": "Recipes.recipes"
    }
  ]
}
```

And my schema :

```
module.exports = {
  definition: `
    type Recipe {
      title: String!
    }
  `,
  query: `
    recipes: Recipe
  `,
  resolver: {
    Query: {
      recipes: {
        description: 'Return a single Recipe',
        resolver: 'Recipes.recipes'
      }
    }
  }
};
```

My Query return me error 403. But, if i try my URL with CURL command, i've my correct response.

Anyone know if i need to add other param' for GraphQL Query without policies ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Your route `/receipes` has a `config` key missing. So make sure to add it.
Then when you are requesting this route, make sure you allow your users to use this route.

Here is some docs about that https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/plugins/users-permissions.html#manage-roles-permissions

About your GraphQL query - there is some documentation here: https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/plugins/graphql.html#customise-the-graphql-schema